# C++ passing a class as an argument

Tags: c++, class, arguments

I have the following header file:

app.h

```
#include "log.h"

void CreateAudio(udtPhrase &uPhrase,CLog *uLog);
```

The error I get is 'CLog': 'class' Type redefinition

Can anyone help?
I am not sure what else is important to mention.

Thank you.

Comment: Dusting off the slightly foggy waterford sphere, either you did not fencepost your `log.h` header internally with include guards or you failed to terminate the `CLog` class with a semi-colon. I'm hedging my bets on the former of these. Seeing the *real* `log.h` header along with how it is included in whatever .cpp file that *this* header is also being included in would confirm/squelch that suspicion.

Comment: Did you write the CLog class, that would be useful to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the log.h file, adding

```
#pragma once
```

That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've an include Problem, maybe you include `log.h` twice. You've to use an include guard.

**test.h**

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

struct foo {
    int member;
};

#endif /* TEST_H */
```

Now if you include this `test.h` twice the `struct foo` will defined once, because `TEST_H` is already defined.

UPDATE:
For a deeper look take a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are including log.h twice. You should add some header guards at least:

```
#ifndef some_unique_token_for_log_h
#define some_unique_token_for_log_h

definitions

#endif
```

This should prevent your error. 
Even better if you can avoid including log.h in app.h.
You can do a forward declaration of CLog in app.h and remove the include. The forward declaration looks like this:

```
class CLog;
```

The benefit here is that is you have a bigger project you won't need to recompile a lot of code. I.e. if there's also util.h that includes app.h but doesn't use Clog at all, then you can avoid recompiling it when log changes.

Comment: I changed the header to the following: #pragma once
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
#include "structures.h"
#include "audiodata.h"
#include "clsWString2.h"
#include "clsTree.h"

#IFNDEF some_unique_token_for_log_h
#DEFINE some_unique_token_for_log_h

#include "log.h"

#ENDIF

Comment: you need to add the header guard to log.h. You should add one for every .h file you have, using a different token.

Comment: #IFNDEF some_unique_token_for_log_h
#DEFINE some_unique_token_for_log_h

#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

#ENDIF

class CLog 
{
  public:
    CLog(wstring filename);
    ~CLog();
 void WriteString(wstring uString);
  private:
    wofstream m_stream;
 wstring m_sPath;
}; Like that?????

Comment: @tmighty Preprocessor directives are lower case: `#ifndef`.